# could not validate with the hashed password using Python

Tags: python, hash, bcrypt

I need one help. I need to validate hashed password with user input password while login using Python. I am explaining my code below.

```
from bcrypt import hashpw, gensalt
def signsave(request):
    """This function helps to save signup data"""

    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('uname')
        password = request.POST.get('pass')
        con_pass = request.POST.get('conpass')
        if password == con_pass:
            hashed = hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), gensalt(13))
            passw = User(
                uname=name,
                password=hashed
            )
            passw.save()
            message = "Registered successfully"
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html',
                          {'msg': message})
        else:
            message = "The password did not match "
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/signup.html',
                          {'msg': message})
```

Here I am hashing the user input password using Bcrypt and storing it into database.

```
def loginsave(request):
    """This function helps to login the user """

    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.POST.get('pass')
        uname = request.POST.get('uname')
        if password == '':
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html', {})
        else:
            per = User.objects.all().filter(Q(uname__icontains=uname)).count()
            if per > 0:
                user = User.objects.filter(Q(uname__icontains=uname))
                for use in user:
                    uid = use.id
                    user_name = use.uname
                    enc_pass = use.password
                hashed = hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), gensalt(13))
                if hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), hashed) == enc_pass:
                    request.session['id'] = uid
                    return render(request, 'bookingservice/home.html',
                                  {'count': per, 'username': user_name})
                else:
                    return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html', {})
            else:
                return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html', {})
```

Here I am retrieving the hashed password from DB and matched it with the user input value. In this case the valid password is also not matching while user login. I need what ever the password has stored in hashed format in DB that will again match when user will login. Please help.

Comment: Haven't used bcrypt, but don't you think you should save your salt value also?
Reason being generated salts might be different

Comment: Can you make this correct but my requirement is I have to use the `Bcrypt` hashing algorthim.

Comment: I would suggest you to generate the salt, then save it in user model. While verifying the login, get the hashed password, the salt used while hashing and then check if the entered password matches with the saved password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The salts are stored inside the hash of password by bcrypt.

Use the `checkpw` method in bcrypt.

```
from bcrypt import hashpw, gensalt, checkpw

def loginsave(request):
    """This function helps to login the user """

    if request.method == 'POST':
        password = request.POST.get('pass')
        uname = request.POST.get('uname')
        if password == '':
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html', {})
        else:
        per = User.objects.all().filter(Q(uname__icontains=uname)).count()
        if per > 0:
            user = User.objects.filter(Q(uname__icontains=uname))
            for use in user:
                uid = use.id
                user_name = use.uname
                enc_pass = use.password
            hashed = hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), user_salt)
            if hashpw(password.encode('utf8'), hashed) == enc_pass:
            if checkpw(password, enc_pass):
                request.session['id'] = uid
                return render(request, 'bookingservice/home.html',
                              {'count': per, 'username': user_name})
            else:
                return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html', {})
        else:
            return render(request, 'bookingservice/login.html', {})
```

Comment: Did as per you but getting error `Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing` while login.